# In python 3, other than in a user defined function, where else can I use the keyword/statement "pass"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I understand that you can use "pass" in a user defined function, say, when you do not want to put anything in it at the moment. Where else can I possibly use this keyword? When assigning it to a variable for example, I get an error: `my_item = pass` Why is this happening and where else can I use this keyword at?

Answer (score 3):

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) is, by itself, an entire statement, and can be used *anywhere* a *statement* is expected, but almost always are found in the body of a compound statement.

```
def foo():
    pass

if True:
    pass

for x in y:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

with foo as bar:
    pass
```

etc.

It is typically used where *some* statement is needed to fill an otherwise empty code block. Note that since any expression can be used as a statement (a so-called expression statement), you can sometimes use a doc string in place of a `pass` statement:

```
class FooError(ValueError):
    '''A very specific kind of ValueError'''
```

instead of

```
# Legal, but unnecessary
class FooError(ValueError):
    '''A very specific kind of ValueError'''
    pass
```

You can only place an *expression*, not a statement, on the right-hand side of an assignment statement, which is why `my_item = pass` is a syntax error.

Comment: I think the most useful place for a `pass` is after an `except` when you just want to ignore the exception.

Comment: That gets overused, though. Too many exceptions that *shouldn't* be ignored, are.

Comment: Just like any aspect of programming it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot if you don't pay attention. But sometimes ignoring an exception is exactly what you need.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think that makes it more useful than any other use of `pass`. (Though the only justification for that sentence I can think of is to use a `str` literal in place of a comment plus `pass` even where the string won't be saved as a doc string for something. `pass` has the advantage of not having to be evaluated like an f-string would.)